# Is it wrong to add instance variables to a Controller?

Tags: grails, scope, grails-controller

If I want to share an object between multiple methods in a controller, is it wrong to create an instance var?  E.g.

```
class MyController {
    def index() {
        def user = verifyUserLogin()
        [messages:getMessages(user)]
    }

    private verifyUserLogin() {
        ...
        return user
    }

    private getMessages(user) {
        ...do something with `user`...
        return messages
    }
}
```

would become

```
class MyController {
    private user

    def index() {
        verifyUserLogin()
        [messages:getMessages()]
    }

    private void verifyUserLogin() {
        ...
        this.user = user
        return
    }

    private getMessages() {
        ...do something with `user`...
        return messages
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that `verifyUserLogin` and `getMessages` should be services

Answer (score 2):

Grails controllers are not singleton they are created for every request so it should not be any issue to have instance level variables.

However I personally prefer to not to declare instance level variables as much as possible, because when code starts becoming lengthy it becomes difficult to figure out the flow of the code that initializes and uses the variables.

I rather choose to pass them as parameters. However there's no such rule of thumb and it highly depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks @sudhir - this was my thinking, so it's good to have a confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way - for Servlets at least - of storing state between controllers, i.e. passing information between requests is to use the [`session`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html) object.

```
class MyController(){
   def index(){
       session.user = getUser()
   }

   def postex(){
       def user = session.user
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info.  However, in this case I'm not trying to pass information between requests, just between methods in the same request.

Comment: In that case, you would want to create a POJO and pass it to your method arguments: `getMessages(User user)`. Controllers are there to render the view. A method call like getting messages for a particular user would probably belong in a User domain class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In grails 3.2.1 the default scope of controllers changed from "prototype", controller instance per request, to "singleton", one instance of each controller.

This made instance variables in controllers no longer safe unless you change the scope!

https://docs.grails.org/3.2.1/ref/Controllers/scope.html singleton
https://docs.grails.org/3.2.0/ref/Controllers/scope.html prototype

If you do want to use instance variables in a controller change the scope `static scope = "prototype"`.

Rather than use instance variables you can set variables on the request (as request attributes). `request.user = user` Note that these will persist for the life of the request (visible to all interceptors and views traversed by the request).